# How to get country based time zone in date format in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying the following query to get the orders and order date as "Mon Jan 01 12:55:55 2016 IST" format, where IST is Indian Standard Time, but I am able to get "Mon Jan 01 12:55:55 2016".

I don't know how to get the time zone. I mean which parameter has to be passed to get it. Could you please help me in resolving this.

```
SELECT ORDERID AS ORD_ID, TO_CHAR(ORDERDATE, 'Dy Mon dd HH24:MI:SS yyyy') AS ORDER_DATE
FROM ORDER
```

Thanks
Hanumanth Reddy.

Comment: I do not understand what you want

Comment: show table result and your expected ouput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the data type of column `ORDERDATE`. Data types `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` do not contain any time zone information. In such case you can append `IST` only as static text, for example like this.

```
SELECT ORDERID AS ORD_ID, 
   TO_CHAR(ORDERDATE, 'Dy Mon dd HH24:MI:SS yyyy')||' IST' AS ORDER_DATE
FROM ORDER;
```

```
SELECT ORDERID AS ORD_ID, 
   TO_CHAR(ORDERDATE, 'Dy Mon dd HH24:MI:SS yyyy "IST"') AS ORDER_DATE
FROM ORDER;
```

In case data type of `ORDERDATE` is `TIMESTAMP` you can also attach your time zone and use this for output:

```
SELECT ORDERID AS ORD_ID, 
   TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(ORDERDATE , 'Asia/Calcutta'), 'Dy Mon dd HH24:MI:SS yyyy TZD') AS ORDER_DATE
FROM ORDER;
```

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta';
SELECT ORDERID AS ORD_ID, 
   TO_CHAR(ORDERDATE AT LOCAL, 'Dy Mon dd HH24:MI:SS yyyy TZD') AS ORDER_DATE
FROM ORDER;
```

In case data type of `ORDERDATE` is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` you can simply do:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta';
SELECT ORDERID AS ORD_ID, 
   TO_CHAR(ORDERDATE, 'Dy Mon dd HH24:MI:SS yyyy TZD') AS ORDER_DATE
FROM ORDER;
```

Note, apart from the last query all of these will work properly only if values in `ORDERDATE` are stored as 'Asia/Calcutta' time.

Another note, you cannot make `ALTER SESSION SET TIME ZONE = 'IST';` or `FROM_TZ(ORDERDATE, 'IST')`. **IST** could also mean "Israel Standard Time" or "Iceland Standard Time" (and maybe even more), thus you will get an error in Oracle. Time zone name `Asia/Kolkata` is also fine, provided you have a recent time-zone file installed at your database.

Comment: SELECT ORDERID AS ORD_ID, TO_CHAR(ORDERDATE AT LOCAL, 'Dy Mon dd HH24:MI:SS yyyy TZD') AS ORDER_DATE FROM ORDER;

Its worked !!
Thanks.